# ProGuard, I am getting errors

Tags: android, proguard

So this is my first time with proguard, I tried a couple of things, read about it on the internet but I am stuck here and I could use some help

## I have jars in my libs folder

Here is the proguard appname.txt file:

```
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends org.cmc.music.clean.NameRectifier.*
-keep public class * extends org.cmc.music.clean.NameRectifier
-keep public class * org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping
-keep public class * org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping.*
-keep public class org.cmc.music.*
-keep public class com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}
-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars libs/MyID3_for_Android.jar
-libraryjars libs/stackblur.jar
```

Here is the properties file:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-PlayMee.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../../Workspace-mine/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Logcat:

```
  [2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee] proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '{' at 'org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping' in line 9 of file 'D:\android\Workspace\PlayMee\proguard-PlayMee.txt',
[2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee]   included from argument number 4
[2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:678)
[2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
[2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:138)
[2014-07-07 14:07:48 - PlayMee]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Comment: What exactly is on line no 9? It seems confusing. Can you post your complete proguard file as one.

Comment: Line 9 is expecting a "{". Sure you closed all your classes there?

Comment: @HiemanshuSharma dpne,please have a look

Comment: @Paul seems like it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are directly using jar `org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping` classes,
In the progaurd-config file line 
`-keep public class * org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping` 
remove * from that and change it to 
`-keep public class org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping`
If you are extending the classes from `org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping` then change the same line to `-keep public class * extends org.cmc.music.myid3.ID3v2DataMapping`

You have to repeat the same step for next line as well.